# the distance from the origin is independent of the orientation (as measured by the angle)

Tags: geometry, statistics, trigonometry

The question is from Casella's statistical inference 4.20. The question is: $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent $n(0 ,\sigma^2)$ random variables. Let $Y_1 = X_1^2 + X_2^2$,  and $Y_2 = \frac{X_1}{\sqrt{Y_1}}$.

We can prove that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent. But the question also asks "interpret this result geometrically".

The solution said: $Y_1$ is the square of the distance from $(X_1, X_2)$ to
the origin. $Y_2$ is the cosine of the angle between the positive x1-axis and the line from
$(X_1, X_2)$ to the origin.

I don't quite understand the geometric meaning of $Y_2$ here. I know if $(X_1, X_2)$ is a point in the first quadrant, then $Y_2$ is the cosine of the angle between the positive x-axis and the line from
$(X_1, X_2)$ to the origin. But what if in other quadrants?